# jQuery script for checking if input has any value. Issue in IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I've got the script for checking if an input isn't empty. It works in Firefox, but if I switch to Chrome or IE, button is enabled even if I submit an empty string. Does anybody know any solution for this issue?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

 $('.comment_button').attr('disabled',true);

 $('.comment_input').keyup(function(){
    if ($.trim($(this).val()).length != 0)  {
        $('.comment_button').attr('disabled', false);
    }
    else
    {
        $('.comment_button').attr('disabled', true);        
    }
 })
 });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a typo in your code `'` is missing after selector

Use `$('.comment_input')` instead of `$('.comment_input)`

In line

```
$('.comment_input).keyup(function(){
```

**Edit:** use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Working code JS:

```
 $('.comment_button').prop('disabled', true);
 $('.comment_input').keyup(function () {
      $('.comment_button ').prop('disabled', $.trim($(this).val()).length == 0);
 });
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="comment_input" name="somethng"/>
<button class="comment_button">something</button>
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DZWsK/)